# How do I get PyDev in eclipse to use pip3?

Tags: python, eclipse, homebrew, pydev, macos-sierra

How do I point my PyDev setup to pip3?

**Environment:**

> macOS Sierra (10.12.6)
>
> python3.6.3 through homebrew
>
> Eclipse Oxygen (4.7.1a)
>
> PyDev for Eclipse 6.0 from Eclipse Marketplace

[image]

Comment: Please try PyDev 6.1.0 (just released) and let me know if it works for you.

Comment: Thank you for the fix Fabio, appreciate it. If your comment as an answer I'll mark this question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was a known issue on `PyDev 6.0.0`.

`PyDev 6.1.0` fixed this issue (it will now do `python -m pip` if it is not able to find the pip executable where it was expected to be -- which is actually a common scenario an many cases).

Comment: thanks for the quick turn around, it wouldn't let me upvote since I lack the reputation