# Eclipse and Pydev issue

Tags: eclipse, numpy, ubuntu, pip, pydev

I run Eclipse 2021.3 with PyDev installed on Ubuntu 20.10. I also have python 3.8.8 installed + pip. But for some reason I cannot use numpy library in Eclipse. It says I have no pip installed. Which I do have:

[image]

I did `pip install numpy` in Ubuntu terminal, I have the library.

[image]

I added path to numpy location, it doesn't help

[image]

Comment: There is no Eclipse 12.3. Maybe Eclipse 2021-03? The PyDev version would be more important. In case of PyDev 6.0.0, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/47161942/6505250

Answer (score 0):

I just stopped using Flathub package and downloaded executable from eclipse foundation website, it worked right away.